# iOS, Custom Table View

Tags: ios, arrays, image, tableview

I need to draw a table view in the same picture:

[image]

What do I need to add to the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method? Because I created the `NSArray` that has the data, but it is displayed as a list:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
        //cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text =[list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.255 green:0.239 blue:0.239 alpha:1];;

    UITableViewCell *cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell1.textLabel.text =[list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell1.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.255 green:0.239 blue:0.239 alpha:1];;


    UIView * v = [[UIView alloc] init];
    v.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = v;


    return cell;


}
```

Comment: Please show your code output

Comment: Take a look at http://www.ioscomponents.com/Home/IOSDataGrid

Answer (score 0):

I understand you wish to display a datagrid (from the picture you provided) which cant be done fast/nice in iOS as far as I know.

The dirty way is to customize UITableViewCell so that 1 cell = 1 row and try to make everything render where it is supposed to.

The nice but long way is to use UICollectionView. You will need to customize the flow layout which is what will be time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

You should subclass UITableViewCell -> CustomCell

CustomCell.h -> add some string properties (Name, Addr, Phone, id)
             -> add some labels (UILabel *lblName, lblAddr, 
lblPhone, lblid)

CustomCell.m -> @synthesize properties

Create an image of a grid and load it behind the table
make table transparent
make cell transparent
...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.lblName = [UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRectMake(x,y,w,h)) // enter values to correspond with your picture
        //... do the same for other controls in your custom cell
        //cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    }

    NSDictionary *dicData = [arElements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell.lblName setText:[dicData valueForKey:@"name"]];
    // ... do the same for all properties

    return cell;
}
```

In basics this is it, and if you want you can create cell in nib, only thing than is that controls should be than IBOutlets and you wont have the

```
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.lblName = [UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRectMake(x,y,w,h)) // enter values to correspond with your picture
        //... do the same for other controls in your custom cell
        //cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    }
```

block, cause it will be loaded from xib...